# css de pixeles a porcentajes

Tags: css

Este es mi código he estado cambiando todo de pixeles a porcentajes porque quiero hacer mi pagina web adaptable a celulares pero se me ha dañado la x de cerrar que sale muy grande.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
* *, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    body {
 background: #000000;
 color: #000000;
} 
header, footer {
 background: #000000;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 20%
 margin:20% auto;

}

header nav {
 background: #000000;
 overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
 float:right;
}
 header nav ul li a {
  padding: 10% 20%;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;


 }
  header nav ul li a:hover {
   background: #55d737;
  }
 
.main {
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  padding: : 0%
  
} 


.main aside,
.main .article{
  padding: 2%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.main .iz{
  width: 15%;
}
.main .de {
 width: 15%
}
.iz{
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  order: 1;
}

.de{
  background: white;
  order: 3;
}

.article{
  order: 2;
  width: 70%;
  background: white;
  
}

article{
  background: white;
  margin: 5%;
}

footer {background: #000;
color:#fff;
clear:both
padding:10% 0%;
text-align: center;
}

.centro {
 text-align: center;
}

a.open{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 2% 2% 0% #000;
 

}


section.modalDialog{
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
 z-index: 2;
}

section.modalDialog:target{
 display: block;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top:0px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 5px;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #000;
}

section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0% 0% 10% #000;
 border-radius: 5%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 5% auto;
 padding: 5%;
 position: relative;
 width: 60%;
}

.diferencia {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.diferente{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .main {
  width: 100%
 }
 .main .iz {
  width: 100%
 }
 .main .de {
  width: 100%
 }
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Bienvenidos</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3473978549309154",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagenes/ale2.jpg">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "enviar mensaje masivo outlook office ",
  "description": "las personas lo reciben como que si estuviera destinado solo a ellos y no como una cadena,  cada persona verá su propia dirección de correo en el mensaje y no la del resto de contactos",
  "thumbnailUrl": [
    "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1LhkxeHZm0A/hqdefault.jpg"
   ],
  "uploadDate": "2017-10-23T19:57:00",
  "duration": "PPT4M28S",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LhkxeHZm0A",
  "interactionCount": "67"
}
</script>
  

<div class="logotipo"><img src="imagenes/ale2.jpg" width="70" alt="logotipo"> </div>
<aside class="arriba">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </aside>

  <nav>
  <ul><li>
  <div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

  <section class="main"><aside class="de">
    <h3></h3>
    <p><a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html">acceso a incognito desde el icono principal</a></p></br>
<p><a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"> capturar pantalla sin paint</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html">conocer la clave de windows instalada en tu equipo</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html">configurar el microfono para que se escuche bien en audio/video</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html">convertir ventana a pestaña y viceversa</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html">desactivar, activar cookies en chrome</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html">cortar video de youtube</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html">conocer dns, direccion ip, gategay o puerta de enlace predeterminada y mascara de subred</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html">enviar mensaje masivo outlook office</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html">añadir excepciones a avira</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html">hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html">localizar los archivos de la grabadora de sonido</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html">guardar sesion en chrome rapidamente</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html">averigua que significa la k en youtube</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html">ocultar informacion y partes de video</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html">solucionar el error de rejected git push heroku master</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html">traducir texto rapidamente</a></p></br>

<p><a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html">gesto del mouse pack para cambio inesperado de aplicaciones en windows</a> </p></br>
  </aside>
  <aside class="iz">
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
  </aside>
  <section class="article">
    <article>
      <h2>Tutoriales</h2><br>

       <p class="centro"><a href="paginas principales/rejected git push heroku master.html"><img src="imagenes/1.jpg" width="150" alt="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master" title="solucion a rejeted git push heroku master"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/enviar mensaje masivo.html"><img src="imagenes/2.jpg" width="150" alt="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office" title="enviar mensaje masivo outlook office"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/traducir texto.html"><img src="imagenes/3.jpg" width="150" alt="traducir texto rápidamente" title="traducir texto rápidamente"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/google ncr.html"><img src="imagenes/4.jpg" width="150" alt="hacer busquedas globales" title="hacer busquedas globales y en cualquier idioma google ncr"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/k de youtube.html"><img src="imagenes/6.jpg" width="150" alt="k de youtube" title="k de youtube"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/grabadora.html"><img src="imagenes/7.jpg" width="150" alt="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido" title="localización de archivos de la grabadora de sonido"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/clavewindows.html"><img src="imagenes/8.jpg" width="150" alt="Conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows" title="conocer la contraseña instalada de tu windows"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/excepciones avira.html"><img src="imagenes/9.jpg" width="150" alt="añadir excepciones de avira" title="añadir excepciones de avira"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/acceso incognito.html"><img src="imagenes/10.jpg" width="150" alt="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono" title="acceso directo a incognito desde el icono google chrome"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/direccion ip.html"><img src="imagenes/11.jpg" width="150" alt="direccion ip dns etcetera" title="obtener dirección ip, gateway, dns, mascara de subred"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/vista windows.html"><img src="imagenes/12.jpg" width="150" alt="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8" title="cambio de accdidenta de aplicaciones de windows 8"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/captura de pantalla.html"><img src="imagenes/13.jpg" width="150" alt="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint" title="atajo para capturar pantalla sin paint"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/cookies chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/14.jpg" width="150" alt="desactivar cookies en chrome" title="desactivar cookies en chrome"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/configmicrofono.html"><img src="imagenes/15.jpg" width="150" alt="configurar microfono" title="configurar microfono"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/ocultar video.html"><img src="imagenes/16.jpg" width="150" alt="ocultar información de video" title="Tapar información de video"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/cortar video.html"><img src="imagenes/17.jpg" width="150" alt="cortar video de youtube" title="cortar video de youtube"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/guardar sesión chrome.html"><img src="imagenes/18.jpg" width="150" alt="guardar sesión e chrome rápidamente" title="guarda sesión en chrome rápidamente"></a>

       <a href="paginas principales/convertir ventana a pestaña.html"><img src="imagenes/5.jpg" width="150" alt="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa" title="convertir ventana a pestaña y vicecersa"></a></p>
    </article>
  </section>
  
</section>
  
   
 <footer><p>Portoviejo-Manabí-Ecuador</p></footer>
  




</body>
</html>
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul><li>
  <div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta anexando el código HTML, para que sea más viable identificar el problema.

Comment: no genera el resultado de la foto, mejora tu pregunta porfavor

Comment: la parte que importa esta desde open en adelante sino que agregué todo para que vieran que casi todo esta en porcentaje

Comment: @AlexandraLoor a los usuarios que quieran ayudarte les ayudaria mucho un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en el padding declarado aquí

```
header nav ul li a {
    padding: 10% 20%;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Si necesitas ese estilo puedes sobrecargar tu `a.close` con un padding pequeño

```
a.close {
    padding: 0.1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes adaptar la clase que contiene la `X` por ejemplo

si tienes una clase que se llame `ejemplo` en el CSS

**debes llamar**

```
@media (max-width: 540px) {

.ejemplo {
/*colocas el tamaño que quieras cuando la pagina quede en los pixeles menor a 540px*/
width:123px;//ejemplo
} 

}
```

Si no tienes una clase mejor es agregarla

espero te sirva

Comment: hola amigo no estoy preguntando como adaptar, estoy preguntando porque el cuadro de la x sale tan grande y como puedo solucionarlo, de todas maneras gracias por tu respuesta